# LDAP query with exchange object

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, exchange-server

I'm trying to get some attributes by ldap query as follows:

```
import win32com.client
ldap="SELECT cn, displayName From 'LDAP://DC=abc,DC=com' WHERE legacyExchangeDN = '{}'"
c = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
c.Open('Provider=ADsDSOObject')
rs,rc = c.Execute(ldap.format(dn))
while not rs.EOF:
    for e in rs.fields:
        print('{}: {}'.format(e.Name, e.Value))
    print()
    rs.MoveNext()
```

But it doesn't work if dn are the following two values.

```
/o=sinotrans/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=myserver/cn=Microsoft Public MDB
/o=sinotrans/ou=first administrative group/cn=configuration/cn=servers/cn=myserver/cn=microsoft system attendant
```

I think the exchange object is different from active directory user. But how to change the ldap query expression? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Well you would have to tell us what the objects do actually look like.

Comment: @EJP It's an exchange public folder object and locates in `'CN=SG1-PF1,CN=SG1,CN=InformationStore,CN=myserver,CN=Servers,CN=Hq Administrator GroupA,CN=Administrative Groups,CN=abc,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=intranet,DC=sinotrans'`. Its legacyExchangeDN value is `'/o=sinotrans/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=myserver/cn=Microsoft Public MDB'`. The above codes can find out any active directory user by legacyExchangeDN. I guess the ldap path result in it doesn't work for the exchange object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that exchange object is stored at `CN=Configuration,DC=intranet,DC=sinotrans` and it's necessary to bind DC server with administrator credential. The following code works with suitiable user name, password and LDAP path.

```
import win32com.client

adoConnection = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
adoCommand = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Command')
adoRecordset = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Recordset')

adoConnection.Provider = 'ADSDSOObject'
adoConnection.Properties('User ID').Value = 'user'
adoConnection.Properties('Password').Value = 'password'
adoConnection.Properties('Encrypt Password').Value = True
adoConnection.Properties('ADSI Flag').Value = 1 
adoConnection.Open('Active Directory Provider')

adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection
adoCommand.Properties('Page Size').Value = 1000

ldap = '''\
SELECT cn, mail
From 'LDAP://CN=Configuration,DC=abc,DC=com'
WHERE legacyExchangeDN = '/o=abc/ou=first administrative group/cn=configuration/cn=servers/cn=myserver/cn=microsoft public mdb'
'''

adoCommand.CommandText = ldap
adoRecordset.Open(adoCommand)
while not adoRecordset.EOF:
    print('{} {}'.format(adoRecordset('cn'), adoRecordset('mail')))
    adoRecordset.MoveNext()
adoRecordset.Close()

adoConnection.Close()
```